# Are there any good 2D fighting game engines that can be used to make a commercial product?

Tags: 2d, cross-platform

I'm looking for a good 2D fighting game engine based on sprites. I really dont care much about which language that it is programmed in.  Specifically I'm looking for an engine I can use for a game I can sell later and could be exportable to different systems.

Something like 2D Fighter Maker or MUGEN would be great, but that could have a product sold using the tech.

Comment: "M.U.G.E.N is free for non-commercial use. If you have other needs, just ask us." Contact them and see if they're willing to work out a new licencing agreement in exchange for compensation. Unless you are looking for something free.

Comment: i dont really care if is free or not, i just want to know some engine where i can develop a 2D fighting game, and then i can sold it. if it is not, well i think i must develop one ahaha

Comment: Carols I am a iPhone developer and have a 2d fighting game engine, maybe we can chat. un4real82ataol.com if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

http://kokusaifightingengine.blogspot.com/

This looks pretty promising and it is build on the c# xna 4.0 This platform is very powerful when it comes to publishing content for Windows, Windows phone 7 and Xbox.

It also looks like it comes with some good editing modules for helping you get your game up and running in no time.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows i would buy DarkBasic Pro from TGC (BASIC Code).
You can develop 2D and 3D commercial games for Windows.
DarkBasic Pro is also compatible with TGC Plug-in's

If you want cross platform 2D game development use App Game Kit (BASIC Code).
App Game Kit has a website: [www.appgamekit.com](http://www.appgamekit.com).

Both are available from [www.thegamecreators.com](http://www.thegamecreators.com) .

Answer (score 0):

### **[java-fighting-game-engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-fighting-game-engine/)**

*"A modular fighting game engine for the Java SE and Android platform."*

This has a well-written codebase, but the demo games included need much polish.

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D is a great choice. It uses sprites. There is ton of tutorials and documentation available on this game engine so learning will be easy. In Unity the are limitless possibilities you can achieve with the scripting, there's a choice of three languages but mainly two are used JavaScript and C#. You can easily create a 2D/3D game for the web and many other platforms.